# How to get a single result from a SQL query in python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-db-api

Is there an elegant way of getting a single result from an SQLite SELECT query when using Python?

for example:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('db_path.db')
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(value) FROM table")

for row in cursor:
    for elem in row:
        maxVal = elem
```

is there a way to avoid those nested `for`s and get the value directly? I've tried

```
maxVal = cursor[0][0]
```

without any success.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Cursor.fetchone()](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) :

```
cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Answer (score 9):

Or you could write a wrapper function that, given SQL, returns a scalar result:

```
def get_scalar_result(conn, sql):
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)

    return cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

I apologize for the possibly less than syntactically correct Python above, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 7):

**Be careful, accepted answer might cause `TypeError`!**

Due to `fetchone()` documentation:

> Fetches the next row of a query result set, returning a single sequence, **or None when no more data is available.**

So with some SQL queries `cursor.fetchone()[0]` could turn into `None[0]` which leads to raising `TypeError` exception.

**Better way to get first row or `None` is:**

`first_row = next(cursor, [None])[0]`

If SQL query is empty, `next` will use default value `[None]` and get first element from that list without raising exceptions.

Comment: if you have `row = cursor.fetchone()`, you can use the expression `row and row[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using pysqlite which has the built in `cursor.fetchone`

```
cursor.execute("select value from table order by value desc limit 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) can be used to extract the scalar value from the result tuple.

By iterating over the cursor (or `cursor.fetchall`)if there are multiple rows:

```
for result, in cursor:
    print(result)
```

Or using `cursor.fetchone` if there is a single row in the resultset:

```
result, = cur.fetchone()
print(result)
```

In both cases the trailing comma after `result` unpacks the element from the single-element tuple.  This is the same as the more commonly seen

```
a, b = (1, 2)
```

except the tuples only have one element:

```
a, = (1,)
```

Answer (score -1):

`select count(*) from ... groupy by ...` returns `None` instead of `0`,
so `fetchone()[0]` would lead to an exception.

Therefore

```
def get_scalar_from_sql(sqlcur, sqlcmd):
    # select count(*) from .... groupy by ... returns None instead of 0
    sqlcur.execute(sqlcmd)
    scalar = 0
    tuple_or_None = sqlcur.fetchone()
    if not tuple_or_None is None:
        (scalar,) = tuple_or_None
    return scalar
```

Answer (score -5):

or you can try :
`cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table where name='martin'")`