# How do i get the password from the SQL database without it quoting the output?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

My code right now is

```
import mysql.connector import hashlib
 
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='!Joshua1',
                               host='127.0.0.1',
                               database='passwordhashtest')
 
cursor = cnx.cursor()
 
Password = input("Enter the password >>")       
hashpass = hashlib.md5(Password.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
 
Email=input("number")
 
passwordcheck='''SELECT b FROM password2 WHERE a = %s AND b = %s'''

values=(Email,hashpass)
 
cursor.execute(passwordcheck,values) 
 
hashedpassindatabase=cursor.fetchone()
 
print(hashedpassindatabase)
 
if hashedpassindatabase==hashpass:
    print("Success!") else:
    print("error")`
```

My output comes out as:

```
('d1133275ee2118be63a577af759fc052',)

error
```

See my problem is the quotes and the comma!
HOW DO I REMOVE THAT!?!?!??!

It seems impossible, i tried everything i can think of!

hashpass is stored as

```
d1133275ee2118be63a577af759fc052
```

If the data im getting from mysql doesnt include the quotes and the comma, then things would get verified pretty easily, but it isnt. THATS WHAT I DONT GET!!!!!!!!! HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7011291/5320906) Q & A.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of a [DB API2 compliant](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) `cursor.fetchone()` is a **sequence** (or `None`).

In your case, the result is a tuple with a single item:

`t = ('d1133275ee2118be63a577af759fc052',)`

To access this item, use `t[0]`.

Or to stick to your variable names:

```
hashedpassindatabase = ('d1133275ee2118be63a577af759fc052',)
actual_value = hashedpassindatabase[0]
print(actual_value)
```

Output:

```
d1133275ee2118be63a577af759fc052
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!! Also, this method of verifying passwords wont be an issue to privacy right?

Comment: Storing password hashes and then comparing hashes is the way to go, while storing plain text passwords is a no-go, so you're on the right track. Off-Topic: MD5 is a weak hash, if you want to use stronger encryption, you could check out [passlib](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/narr/hash-tutorial.html#verifying)