# Why is unwanted characters being printed on the sql query result?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am querying my SQL table using the code below and converted the result to a list. Why is the list having unwanted commas and parenthesis?

The query result

> [(34830,), (34650,), (35050,), (34500,), (35050,), (34500,), (34725,), (34550,), (34725,), (34760,), (34760,)]

It should just return a list with just numbers on it. Right?

The schema is simple  (link text, price int);

What is the problem here? Is there something wrong with my code?

```
    import pymysql

    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='passme',
                             db='hpsize')  # connection obhect to pass the database details


    sql =  "SELECT price FROM dummy WHERE link ='https://www.flipkart.com/bose-noise-cancelling-700-anc-enabled-bluetooth-headset/p/itma57a01d3bd591?pid=ACCFGYZEVVGYM8FP'"


    my_cursor = connection.cursor()

    my_cursor.execute(sql)  

    result = list(my_cursor.fetchall())

    print(result)

    connection.close()
```

The query result

> [(34830,), (34650,), (35050,), (34500,), (35050,), (34500,), (34725,), (34550,), (34725,), (34760,), (34760,)]

Comment: Those are the representation of `tuple`s. Since a query can return multiple columns, the result is a `list` of `tuple` even if the `tuple` is only one element in length.

Comment: Because `cursor.fetchall()` fetches all the rows of a query result. It returns all the rows as a list of tuples.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011291/how-to-get-a-single-result-from-a-sql-query-in-python?r=SearchResults&s=3|17.7034), though focussed more on single-row results.

Comment: To answer your question you could convert it with a simple comprehension. `[i[0] for i in result]`

Comment: @Axe319 Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```py
connection.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
```

instead of `list(my_cursor.fetchall())`

then

```py
result = connection.execute("""SELECT * FROM dummy""").fetchall()
```

or you can also use `strip()` to cut the unwanted part